# Swift sort array of different classes

Tags: swift

I have array that contain items of 2 possible classes, that are different, but each of them have object Date, that is contain object creation date.

What i want is, sort array using that date variable, with newest items first.
I have not found simply solution for that.

Comment: Do the objects share a common base class or a implement a common protocol, or do you have an array of `Any`?

Comment: @Paulw11 they not share any subclass or protocol, but i could create one if need.

Comment: @Paulw11 i did create protocol that have variable - createdDate, and they borth conform to it.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban OK, then your issue is gone since you now have an array of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Subclass your two classes to one protocol, for example

```
protocol HasName {
    var name: String { get set }
}

class Person: HasName {
    var name: String = ""

    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
}

class Car: HasName {
    var name: String = ""

    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
}
```

Creating the array would look like this, in this case.

```
let someArray: [HasName] = [
    Car(name: "mercedes"),
    Person(name: "jason")
]

// you can then now use the `.sort()` array function.

someArray.sort(by: { $0.name > $1.name })
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct `someArray.sort({ $0 > $1 })` ?? no compiler error??

Comment: What Swift version are you using? Also I fixed the code to match Swift 3, @Bilal